# I can't wrap jQuery object around anchor passed to its own onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link that looks this way:

```
<a href='#close' onclick='javascript:RequestClosure(this, event, 1012236);'>Request closure</a>
```

The RequestClosure function looks like this:

```
function RequestClosure(sender, e, partsID)
{
  alert($(sender).html());
}
```

**When the function is executed it shows nothing, like $(sender) does not exist.**
But if I write something like this

```
function RequestClosure(sender, e, partsID)
{
  alert(sender);
  // or this
  alert(sender.href);
}
```

it works and shows href property

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsbin.com/ahine3/2/#noedit) (view source).

Comment: What are you trying to get from the a tag?

Comment: I don't think you'd be getting a jQuery event object by doing it this way.  But, that might not be what you're looking for anyway, and aside from that, passing in 'this' and then doing '$(sender)' should work to create a jQuery object of 'this'.  The example above seems to work as expected in that regard!

Comment: Btw. the `javascript:` label is unnecessary.

Comment: You can't really alert an object, some browsers will alert something like [obj], but alert takes a string, and your not passing in a string. Although, sender.href is a string, so it's able to display it on the screen. if your looking to do something with this object, i'd suggest giving it an id or a name

Answer (score 1):

```
> <a href='#close' onclick='javascript:RequestClosure(this, event, 1012236);'>Request closure</a>
```

The `javascript:` in the onclick attribute vaule is treated as a label, do not use it.

```
> function RequestClosure(sender, e, partsID)
```

By convention, function names starting with a capital letter are reserved for constructors that should be called with `new`.

```
> {
>   alert($(sender).html());
> }
```

The last line would be much more efficient as:

```
alert(sender.innerHTML);
```

since that is what jQuery uses (it also removes the non-standard attributes it adds for event management).

> When the function is executed it shows nothing, like $(sender) does not exist.

One of the joys of jQuery - when things go awry, it likes to silently fail.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys,
The problem was that jQuery file was not correctly included. :(
That was so lame :)